# Powershell pipelining only returns last member of collection

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, pipeline

I have an issue running the following script in a pipeline:

```
Get-Process | Get-MoreInfo.ps1
```

The issue is that only the last process of the collection is being displayed.  How do I work with all members of the collection in the following script:

```
param(    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true,ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
    $Process
)

function Get-Stats($Process)
{

New-Object PSObject -Property @{
Name = $Process.Processname

}

} 
Get-Stats($Process)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
param(    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true,ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
    $Process
)

process{
New-Object PSObject -Property @{
Name = $Process.Processname}
}
```

Edit:

if you need a function:

```
function Get-MoreInfo {
param(    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true,ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
    $Process
)


process{
New-Object PSObject -Property @{
Name = $Process.Processname}
}

}
```

then you can use:

```
. .\get-moreinfo.ps1 # 

Get-Process | Get-MoreInfo
```

Edit after Comment:

[Read about dot sourcing a script](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176949.aspx)

Comment: I would like to use a function, but am unable to get this to work.  Do you mind making a complete sample, and expand on what you mean by `have ready the function in the actual powershell contole`?

Comment: Code in my answer works. -have you copy and paste it? What does't works? I've added a link on my answer to read about dot sourcing.

Answer (score 0):

I you simply create `Get-MoreInfo` as a *Filter* instead of Function, you will get the desired effect.

```
Filter Get-MoreInfo
{
    param(    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true,ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
         $Process
    )
...
```

Comment: Is there any documentation to filters? I just found on some websites about_filters but this is not available in on the technet-site http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347616.aspx

Comment: Don't know, learned about the feature when reading _Powershell in Action_ by Bruce Payette (http://www.manning.com/payette/) - a book that I really recommend anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, both Christian's answer and tbergstedt's answer are *both* valid--and they are essentially equivalent. You can learn more about how and why in my recent article on Simple-Talk.com: [Down the Rabbit Hole- A Study in PowerShell Pipelines, Functions, and Parameters](http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-tools/down-the-rabbit-hole--a-study-in-powershell-pipelines,-functions,-and-parameters/).

In a nutshell, here are the salient points:

1. A function body includes **begin**, **process**, and **end** blocks.
2. A function not explicitly specifying any of the above 3 blocks operates as if all code is in the **end** block; hence the result you initially observed.
3. A **filter** is just another way to write a function without any of the above 3 blocks but all the code is in the **process** block. That is why the above two answers are equivalent.